# How can I train MultinomialNB by solving this error [ValueError: bad input shape (10, 2)]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is the data and then I use countvectorizer after that I use the MultinomialNB() but I get error in that. Please let me know the correct syntax of it.

```
train = [('I love this sandwich.','pos'),
         ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
         ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
         ('This is my best work.', 'pos'),
         ('What an awesome view', 'pos'),
         ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
         ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
         ("I can't deal with this.", 'neg'),
         ('He is my sworn enemy!.', 'neg'),
         ('My boss is horrible.', 'neg')
        ]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()

text_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(list(zip(*train))[0])
print(text_train_cv.toarray())

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_trans = TfidfTransformer()

text_train_tfidf = tfidf_trans.fit_transform(text_train_cv)
print(text_train_tfidf.toarray())



from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(text_train_tfidf , train)
```

This is the error:
ValueError: bad input shape (10, 2)

Comment: Please print text_train_tfidf and show

Comment: o.k sir. I'll show you now.

Comment: Please check it and let me know the syntax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list(zip(*train))[1]` in place of `train` in MultinomialNB.fit().

```
MultinomialNB().fit(text_train_tfidf , list(zip(*train))[1])
```

fit() method requires a single list (Or 1-d array) of labels for `y`. So you need to change your train the same way you were doing it when passing it to CountVectorizer.